# Problem whith cors response (POST application/json). 400 bad request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, post, cors

I have code:

1) ajax

```
addFarmByPost = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.state));
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/farms", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            data: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        })
    }
```

2) Rest controller

```
 @PostMapping("/farms")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addFarm(@RequestBody String farmParam) {...//do }
```

3) Clobal cors configurtion in spring boot application:

```
**@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowCredentials(false)
                        .maxAge(6000);

            }
        };
    }**
```

But when i make a ajax **POST request (application/json)** i have exeption **400 Bad request**. And exception: *Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing.*

Get CORS method is work good. How i can fix it and 
understand the cause of the error.Ty.

Comment: The problem is not about cors like the exception indicates ( Required request body is missing ) the problem is spring can't find the request body to parse. and why you'r using the body as string ??

Comment: Abdou Rayes, I use string because I need to get two java objects. I can say that this configuration work good when i dont use cors in my application.

Comment: can you change the content-type header to application/text

Comment: try settings the header to `text/plain`, cause setting the header to `application/json` will cause spring to look for a corresponding body reader (most of the time it's `Jackson`) and will try to convert it to your target type, in this case it's `String.class` and this will cause an error (i suppose , because i have no idea on the contents of `this.state` in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The exception was here `data: JSON.stringify(this.state)` must be `body: JSON.stringify(this.state)`
Because i use reactJS, i must write `body` not `data` in ajax request
Ty